# What is an overview of the different predestination beliefs?

Tags: predestination

I once saw a listing of around 20 different views of predestination on a site. I can't find it any more. I know my own view is a bit unorthodox, but it works cleanly with the biblical text.

What is an overview of the different predestination beliefs? I'll limit them to perspectives of Christian groups which subscribe to the Apostle's Creed.

You may wish to close this question. I see an answer in Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination

Comment: A better, more organized answer could be given, but it would be a hard answer to write. You might instead ask about specific views, or comparison of, for example, Calvin's with Arminius' view. There should be some closely related questions here.

Comment: @disciple Let's limit the answers to views that are unrelated to Calvin and Arminius, then. Those are plentiful on the web. The list I referred to gave lesser-known views.

Comment: I'm sorry you've not yet received a good answer. There's two close votes as "too broad", so that might be why. It's a big topic. I'm inclined to vote to close as well, but maybe since it's been a few months, and you might have something more clear in mind to ask, I'll hold off for now, hoping you can make an edit to the question.

Comment: @3961 You may close it.